# What are the options set by default when we run ng build --prod

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

When I build my angular application with `ng build --prod` it creates a build for production environment with build optimization, tree-shaking etc.. If I want to make the same kind of build for development environment, what options needs to be passed with `ng build` command? 
Eg.,

```
ng build --configuration=development --aot --buildOptimizer=true --vendorChunk=false
```

Basically, what are the cli options one should pass, to make a dev build exactly similar to prod build(except the configuration)?

Comment: you can choose your environment mode using `--configuration` so, why do you want to remove it.

Comment: I think that will depend what's in your `angular.json`, you can create a new configuration with the same settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the option you already used you should add:

`--outputHashing= all --sourceMap= false --extractCss=true --namedChunks= false --extractLicenses=true --optimization=true`

You can find [here](https://angular.io/cli/build) the list of all available options.

If you check your `angular.json` file, under:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
   // HERE all the used options by default for prod build
   }
}
```

You can read all the used options for a prod build.